# How do I beat the desert temple third room?

Tags: candy-box-2

It's big and empty and I can't get up to the top, what should I do? I can't jump high enough, anti-gravity doesn't seem to do anything either.

My first tactic was to use the octopus summoning crown to create a pile of octopi that I could climb up, but when I teleported to the back of the room they followed me back, trapping me in the entrance.

Comment: [Octopi work](http://i.imgur.com/iCTNMEq.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equip `A tribal summoning spear` and `Boots of introspection` (keeps you grounded so there's no need to use `teleport`). You will also need `Pogo stick` and `A desert bird feather`.

Wait until at least 6 tribal warriors are summoned and jump on the closest one. Continue building layers until you reach the top.

You can use `Black demons` spell destroying all tribal warriors if tribal warrior blocks your way just before you reached the chest.

[image]

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with the boots of introspection - he'se always either too far from the chest, or keeps jumping on top of the damn thing!

Comment: You could also try Shrinking spell, this should trigger chest to open if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Use the staff of summoning, the tribal people will stack to the right. Keep teleporting back and jumping on top of the heap to build up the pile.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did it.  Just keep jumping.  If one lands directly on your head, summon wall of demons and teleport back if necessary.  Keep jumping!  ;)

[image: Wall of Octopi]

Comment: I tried using octopi first, but their staggered piling caused me to quickly get trapped in the tunnel to the left. The tribesmen are nice, rectangular blocks, so they don’t trap you until the second row reaches the left wall.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how it works using Obsidian Wall. Took quite a lot of time, but was worth it :)

Use teleport to switch back and you can use the spear to break through the wall (to get it lower) since using bare hands is painfully slow. It takes about 5 minutes to build this up.

Requirements: pogo stick, Anti Graviti Potion X1, obsidian wall spell

[image: how to use obsidian wall]

Comment: This is amazing, bravo

Answer (score 2):

An easier way with the clones.[image]

Comment: This is good, but requires a lot of cloning potions which probably take longer to make than it would to use spearmen!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I obtained the Pogo Stick, and the cloning method is now working :)

Build a pyramyd of yourself(ves) and jump :)

[image]

Comment: You already posted this yesterday.  There's no need to repost, just edit your existing one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Obsidian Wall, but it's kind of slow.  Put a wall somewhere in the middle of the room, then shoot fireballs at it until it's short enough to jump up on. Then put a new wall after the first one, rinse and repeat.

The advantage of this approach is that you don't have to waste chocolate bars on the spear or the crown.

Note: you should unequip your weapon before, otherwise you will destroy the wall you're standing on.